# Convert Xpath to SQL

Tags: sql, xpath

Previously we were fetching a number of countries from a table. Now the table changed to support multiple languages inside the text cell. The previous SQL statement was:

```
select b.text, a.iso_num, a.iso2, a.iso3, a.kfz, a.ind_member
    from schema.zl_countrycode a, schema.zl_countrycode_lsd b  
        where a.ind_land = 1 and a.kfz is not NULL and dat_end = to_date('99991231','YYYYMMDD') and a.ZL_COUNTRYCODE_id = b.ZL_COUNTRYCODE_LSD_ID order by text
```

The list previously outputted each country in a row.
With the addition of the language selection, the list suddenly doubled in size - because it lists every county in two different languages.

[This is how the table looks with the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJic3.png)

I'm trying to figure out, how to expend the statement to only select each "DE:" value in the text column. After having a quick indirect discussion with the developers, they provided me this XPATH statement:

```
Parentofparent/Parent/Valuestable[name="ZL_COUNTRYCODE"]/Valueclassification[name="TEXT"]/Value/ValueLng[lng="DE"]
```

I don't know the first thing about XPATH and no matter what I have tried so far, it failed.

Please help me out if you're knowledgeable in this field. It's probably an Oracle database, as I have experienced a plethora of Oracle error codes in the last few days.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
SELECT b.TEXT
    ,a.iso_num
    ,a.iso2
    ,a.iso3
    ,a.kfz
    ,a.ind_member
    ,a.de
FROM SCHEMA.zl_countrycode a
JOIN SCHEMA.zl_countrycode_lsd b 
    ON a.ZL_COUNTRYCODE_id = b.ZL_COUNTRYCODE_LSD_ID AND b.spec_lng = 'DE'
WHERE a.ind_land = 1
    AND a.kfz IS NOT NULL
    AND dat_end = to_date('99991231', 'YYYYMMDD')
ORDER BY TEXT
```

Comment: Thank you for replying with an answer. Sadly it didn't work out for me. The response was:
ORA-00904: "B"."ZL_COUNTRYCODE": invalid identifier

I then tried to switch up b with a, and then got the same response:
ORA-00904: "A"."ZL_COUNTRYCODE": invalid identifier

Comment: @Saph1r0 I made an adjustment but it's another shot in the dark since we don't know your actual table layout. If you query the involved tables and post their layout things would be easy, I guess.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work out as well. In the end, I was finally able to have a look at that god-forsaken table. And there was a separate column called "spec_lng" which stored the information - if I knew this earlier, I wouldn't have had to black box guessing all those SQL statements for two days. I nearly lost my mind. Anyway, I replaced the "b.lng" through "b.spec_lng" and it worked. Your tidied up SQL statement was correct! So thank you once more for your help.

Comment: @Saph1r0  Glad to hear this worked out for you. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking ✓ on the left and upvoting (See: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)). Upvoting is a way to say "thanks" and accepting means you confirm the answer solves your problem.